# Link Preview - Instagram Share Sheet

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, ios-sharesheet

How to add photo and title to instagram share sheet?

Using url tag works but unsure how to add image and title

Here is my code:

```
    func shareToInstagram(with url: URL) {
        let imagepngdata = UIImage.pic1.pngData()
        if let url = URL(string: "instagram://sharesheet?url=\(url)") {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: { _ in
                EventTracker.log(.invite_friend_done, withEventProperties: ["Channel": "Instagram handle"])})
        }
    }
```

Now, how do I pass ui image and title for this preview to have these inside when I share via IG DM?